# Yii: Not able to display data correctly on interface

Tags: php, yii

I am a yiibie, I am having an issue in displaying the data the way i want to show it on the interface. I have retrieved the `ngo image` and `ngo name` from the `ngo table` but the images are displayed in a long vertical line whereas i want to show 4 ngo Images in each row. I have made a `Allngo()` in the controller to get all the data from the `ngo table` and a allstory.php file in the view to display the data. This is the code for `NgoController`.

```
<?php

class NgoController extends RController
{
    /**
    * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
    * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
    */
    public $layout='//layouts/admin';

    /**
    * @return array action filters
    */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
//          'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
//          'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request

                    'rights',
                );
    }

    /**
    * Specifies the access control rules.
    * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
    * @return array access control rules
    */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
    * Displays a particular model.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
    */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }
        public function actionNgopage($id)
    {         
               $this->layout='main';
        $this->render('ngopage',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }
        public function actionAllngo()
        {
            $allmodels= Ngo::model()->findAll();
            $this->layout='main';
            $this->render('allngo',array('allmodels'=>$allmodels));
        }


    /**
    * Creates a new model.
    * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Ngo;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Ngo']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Ngo'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Updates a particular model.
    * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
    */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Ngo']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Ngo'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Deletes a particular model.
    * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
    */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
        {
            // we only allow deletion via POST request
            $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

            // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
            if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
        }
        else
            throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
    }

    /**
    * Lists all models.
    */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Ngo');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Manages all models.
    */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new Ngo('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Ngo']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Ngo'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
    * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
    * @return Ngo the loaded model
    * @throws CHttpException
    */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=Ngo::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }

    /**
    * Performs the AJAX validation.
    * @param Ngo $model the model to be validated
    */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='ngo-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for my allngo.php(view file)

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="banner">
        <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseurl;?>/img/ngo-banner.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div><!--banner ending here-->
    <br>
    <div class="ngo-content">
        <div class="row">                           
            <div class="col-md-3">           
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <?php 
                    foreach($allmodels as $model)
                    {
                    ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseurl;?>/img/<?php echo $model->image;?>">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3 style="text-align: center"><?php echo $model->ngo_name;?></h3>
                        <a href="ngo-profile.php">  <button class="btn btn-primary center-block">View Profile</button></a>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>                                 
            </div>                                   
        </div><!--row ending here-->
        <div class="row col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="building2.jpg">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Hope</h3>
                        <a href="ngo-profile.php">  <button class="btn btn-primary center-block">View Profile</button></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--row ending here-->
    </div><!--ngo-content ending here-->                                     
</div><!--content ending here-->
```

And this is the code for my NgoController

```
<?php

class NgoController extends RController
{
    /**
    * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
    * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
    */
    public $layout='//layouts/admin';

    /**
    * @return array action filters
    */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
//          'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
//          'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request

                    'rights',
                );
    }

    /**
    * Specifies the access control rules.
    * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
    * @return array access control rules
    */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
    * Displays a particular model.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
    */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }
        public function actionNgopage($id)
    {         
               $this->layout='main';
        $this->render('ngopage',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }
        public function actionAllngo()
        {
            $allmodels= Ngo::model()->findAll();
            $this->layout='main';
            $this->render('allngo',array('allmodels'=>$allmodels));
        }


    /**
    * Creates a new model.
    * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Ngo;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Ngo']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Ngo'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Updates a particular model.
    * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
    */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Ngo']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Ngo'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Deletes a particular model.
    * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
    */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
        {
            // we only allow deletion via POST request
            $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

            // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
            if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
        }
        else
            throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
    }

    /**
    * Lists all models.
    */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Ngo');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Manages all models.
    */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new Ngo('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Ngo']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Ngo'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
    * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
    * @return Ngo the loaded model
    * @throws CHttpException
    */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=Ngo::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }

    /**
    * Performs the AJAX validation.
    * @param Ngo $model the model to be validated
    */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='ngo-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}
Please help me in doing this, th
```

ank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change the part of code related to the row this

```
        <?php 
            $cnt= 0;
            $nThumbXRow = 4;
            foreach($allmodels as $model) {
                if (cnt%$nThumbXRow == 0){
                    echo "<div class='row'>";
                }
                    echo "<div class='col-md-3'><div class='thumbnail'> 
                            <img src='" . Yii::app()->request->baseurl. "/img/" . $model->image. "'>" .
                          "<div class='caption'>
                            <h3 style='text-align: center'>" . $model->ngo_name ."</h3>
                            <a href='ngo-profile.php'>  <button class='btn btn-primary center-block'>View Profile</button></a>
                            </div></div></div>";


                if (cnt%$nThumbXRow == 0){
                    echo "</div><!-- row ending here -->";
                }
                $cnt++;
            }
        ?>
```

and then for the order change your action this way

```
public function actionAllngo()
    {
        $allmodels= Ngo::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'id DESC'));
        $this->layout='main';
        $this->render('allngo',array('allmodels'=>$allmodels));
    }
```

Comment: thanks mate it worked fine but there is a problem,1) the 1st ngo in the db is coming alone in the first row and 2) when a new ngo is added it comes in the lower row. I want when an new ngo is added in should come in the upper row and so on.

Comment: Ihave solved the 1st problem , just need your help in the second problem, i want that when a ngo is added it should come in the first ngo in the first place.

Comment: Well @SalikAsad if working fine please Mark as accepted and also rate as useful please. And explain better what do you mean whit "when a new  ngo is added is comes in lower row and so on.. seems related to the order set by you  in your query....eventually post a new question with the related with the controller action related to this view

Comment: okay i am posting a new question related to this and will share the link here.

Comment: Why you don't mark also as useful?.  upper arrow left near  the top of the answer..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97001/discussion-between-salik-asad-and-scaisedge).

Comment: I have update the answer with the order but was better a new question so every title question is  coherent with the content ... and the rating

Comment: Eventually post a separated question and I add the answer quickly

Comment: here is the link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093823/yii-how-to-bring-data-in-desc-order-on-desired-page

Comment: This is the link for video uploading i was talking about. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114944/yii-how-to-manage-videos-when-using-multiuploadfiles-extension.. Please have a look at it..!!

Comment: have you looked into my question, i was waiting for your response whole day

Comment: @Salik i'm not at your service, if you like my suggestion well, otherwise i have a lot of problem to solve for my self. Respect please.

Comment: Sorry @scaisEdge i didn't meant that. Well sorry again, I didn't meant to disrespect you.