# Yii: how to bring data in desc order on desired page

Tags: php, yii

I am a yiibie, I am retrieving image and ngo name from the ngo table and able to show them on the desired page, i want to show Ngo's in desc order, I mean that when a new ngo registers it should be displayed as the 1st image on the desired page.
For that this is Ngo controller

```
<?php

class NgoController extends RController
{
    /**
    * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
    * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
    */
    public $layout='//layouts/admin';

    /**
    * @return array action filters
    */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
//          'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
//          'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request

                    'rights',
                );
    }

    /**
    * Specifies the access control rules.
    * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
    * @return array access control rules
    */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
    * Displays a particular model.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
    */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }
        public function actionNgopage($id)
    {         
               $this->layout='main';
        $this->render('ngopage',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }
        public function actionAllngo()
        {
            $allmodels= Ngo::model()->findAll();

            $this->layout='main';
            $this->render('allngo',array('allmodels'=>$allmodels));
        }


    /**
    * Creates a new model.
    * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Ngo;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Ngo']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Ngo'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Updates a particular model.
    * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
    */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Ngo']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Ngo'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Deletes a particular model.
    * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
    */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
        {
            // we only allow deletion via POST request
            $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

            // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
            if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
        }
        else
            throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
    }

    /**
    * Lists all models.
    */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Ngo');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Manages all models.
    */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new Ngo('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Ngo']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Ngo'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
    * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
    * @return Ngo the loaded model
    * @throws CHttpException
    */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=Ngo::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }

    /**
    * Performs the AJAX validation.
    * @param Ngo $model the model to be validated
    */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='ngo-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the view file

                                     
                                         request->baseurl;?>/img/ngo-banner.jpg" class="img-responsive">

```
                                          <?php 
        $cnt= -100;
        $nThumbXRow = 4;
        foreach($allmodels as $model) {
            if ($cnt%$nThumbXRow == 0);

                echo "<div class='col-md-3'><div class='thumbnail'> 
                        <img src='" . Yii::app()->request->baseurl. "/img/" . $model->image. "'>" .
                      "<div class='caption'>
                        <h3 style='text-align: center'>" . $model->ngo_name ."</h3>
                        <a href='ngo-profile.php'>  <button class='btn btn-primary center-block'>View Profile</button></a>
                        </div></div></div>";


            if ($cnt%$nThumbXRow == 0){
                echo "</div><!-- row ending here -->";
            }
            $cnt++;
        }
    ?>         




                                     </div><!--ngo-content ending here-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way

```
public function actionAllngo()
{
    $allmodels= Ngo::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'id DESC'));
    $this->layout='main';
    $this->render('allngo',array('allmodels'=>$allmodels));
}
```

Comment: Will take 11 minutes..!!

Comment: I did not know, I'm sorry

Comment: can you please help me with this.. Nobody responds to my questions except you. Please if you have time, please have a look at it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114944/yii-how-to-manage-videos-when-using-multiuploadfiles-extension

Comment: I'm a little busy these days, maybe I can take a first look today in (my) afternoon