# Yii: How to manage videos when using multiuploadfiles extension

Tags: php, video, yii, multi-upload

I am a yiibie and i am working on uploading of video. I have used the `uploadmultifile` extension and have made changes according to this link `http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/uploadmultifiles/`in my `video view` file and my `videocontroller`. The video successfully gets goes into the `video folder(projectname/video)` but it doesn't comes the database table named `video`. I want that when i create a video via `projectname/video/create` it should be displayed when i type the url `projectname/video/admin` so that i can manage my videos here and after that i can simply display all my videos on the interface. I have been looking for this all around but haven't come up with a sloution, please help me with this.
This is the code for my `Video Controller`

```
<?php

class VideoController extends RController
{
    /**
    * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
    * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
    */
    public $layout='//layouts/admin';

    /**
    * @return array action filters
    */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
//          'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
//          'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
                    'rights',
        );
    }

    /**
    * Specifies the access control rules.
    * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
    * @return array access control rules
    */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
    * Displays a particular model.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
    */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Creates a new model.
    * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    */

public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Video;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
    if(isset($_POST))
        {
      var_dump('ALL POST');
      var_dump($_POST);
    } else {
      var_dump('NO POST'); 
    }

    if(isset($_POST['video']))
    { 
        var_dump('VIDEO POST');
        var_dump($_POST['video']);

        $model->attributes=$_POST['video'];
        $model->video = Video::getInstance($model, 'video');
        if($model->save(false))
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
    'model'=>$model,
    ));
}

    /**
    * Updates a particular model.
    * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
    */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Video']))
        {

            $model->attributes=$_POST['Video'];

            if($model->save())

                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Deletes a particular model.
    * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
    */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
        {
            // we only allow deletion via POST request
            $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

            // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
            if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
        }
        else
            throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
    }

    /**
    * Lists all models.
    */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Video');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Manages all models.
    */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new Video('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Video']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Video'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
       public function actionUpload()
{

        Yii::import("ext.EAjaxUpload.qqFileUploader");

        $folder=Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/video/';// folder for uploaded files
        $allowedExtensions = array("3gp","mp4");//array("jpg","jpeg","gif","exe","mov" and etc...
        $sizeLimit = 100 * 1024 * 1024;// maximum file size in bytes
        $uploader = new qqFileUploader($allowedExtensions, $sizeLimit);
        $result = $uploader->handleUpload($folder);
        $return = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES);

        $fileSize=filesize($folder.$result['filename']);//GETTING FILE SIZE
        $fileName=$result['filename'];//GETTING FILE NAME
        //$img = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');

        echo $return;// it's array
}

    /**
    * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
    * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
    * @return Video the loaded model
    * @throws CHttpException
    */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=Video::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }


    /**
    * Performs the AJAX validation.
    * @param Video $model the model to be validated
    */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='video-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }

}
```

and this is my `view file`

```
<?php
/* @var $this VideoController */
/* @var $model Video */
/* @var $form BSActiveForm */
?>

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.BsActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'video-form',
    // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
    // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
    // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
    // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
    ),

        )); ?>

    <p class="help-block">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<?php //echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

     <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'user_id'); ?>
     <?php

  $this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2',array(
  'name'=>'video[user_id]',
  'data'=>CHtml::listData(User::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'username'), //the whole available list
  'htmlOptions'=>array(
       'placeholder'=>' search User name?',
    //'options'=>$options, //the selected values
    //'multiple'=>'multiple',
    'style'=>'width:530px',
  ),
  ));
    ?> <br><br>
    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
<?php
 $this->widget('ext.EAjaxUpload.EAjaxUpload',
array(
        'id'=>'uploadFile',
        'config'=>array(
               'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('video/upload'),
               'allowedExtensions'=>array("mp4","3gp"),//array("jpg","jpeg","gif","exe","mov" and etc...
               'sizeLimit'=>1000*1024*1024,// maximum file size in bytes
               'minSizeLimit'=>1*1024,
               'auto'=>true,
               'multiple' => true,
               'onComplete'=>"js:function(id, fileName, responseJSON){ alert(fileName); }",
               'messages'=>array(
                                 'typeError'=>"{file} has invalid extension. Only {extensions} are allowed.",
                                'sizeError'=>"{file} is too large, maximum file size is {sizeLimit}.",
                                'minSizeError'=>"{file} is too small, minimum file size is {minSizeLimit}.",
                                'emptyError'=>"{file} is empty, please select files again without it.",
                                'onLeave'=>"The files are being uploaded, if you leave now the upload will be cancelled."
                               ),
               'showMessage'=>"js:function(message){ alert(message); }"
               )

               ));
?>
    <?php //echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'fileName',array('maxlength'=>45)); ?>
    <?php //echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'user_id'); ?>

    <?php echo BsHtml::submitButton('Submit', array('color' => BsHtml::BUTTON_COLOR_PRIMARY)); ?>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

And this is the video model

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "video".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'video':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $video
 * @property integer $user_id
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property User $user
 */
class Video extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return Video the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'video';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('video, user_id', 'required'),
            array('user_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('video', 'length', 'max'=>45),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, video, user_id', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'video' => 'Video',
            'user_id' => 'User',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('video',$this->video,true);
        $criteria->compare('user_id',$this->user_id);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
}
```

This is the create view file

```
<?php
/* @var $this VideoController */
/* @var $model Video */
?>

<?php
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Videos'=>array('index'),
    'Create',
);

$this->menu=array(
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-list','label'=>'List Video', 'url'=>array('index')),
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-tasks','label'=>'Manage Video', 'url'=>array('admin')),
);
?>

<?php echo BsHtml::pageHeader('Create','Video') ?>

<?php $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model)); ?>
```

And this is the _form.php file for video

```
<?php
/* @var $this VideoController */
/* @var $model Video */
/* @var $form BSActiveForm */
?>

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.BsActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'video-form',
    // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
    // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
    // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
    // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
    ),

        )); ?>

    <p class="help-block">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<?php //echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

     <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'user_id'); ?>
     <?php

  $this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2',array(
  'name'=>'video[user_id]',
  'data'=>CHtml::listData(User::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'username'), //the whole available list
  'htmlOptions'=>array(
       'placeholder'=>' search User name?',
    //'options'=>$options, //the selected values
    //'multiple'=>'multiple',
    'style'=>'width:530px',
  ),
  ));
    ?> <br><br>
    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
<?php
 $this->widget('ext.EAjaxUpload.EAjaxUpload',
array(
        'id'=>'uploadFile',
        'config'=>array(
               'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('video/upload'),
               'allowedExtensions'=>array("mp4","3gp"),//array("jpg","jpeg","gif","exe","mov" and etc...
               'sizeLimit'=>1000*1024*1024,// maximum file size in bytes
               'minSizeLimit'=>1*1024,
               'auto'=>true,
               'multiple' => true,
               'onComplete'=>"js:function(id, fileName, responseJSON){ alert(fileName); }",
               'messages'=>array(
                                 'typeError'=>"{file} has invalid extension. Only {extensions} are allowed.",
                                'sizeError'=>"{file} is too large, maximum file size is {sizeLimit}.",
                                'minSizeError'=>"{file} is too small, minimum file size is {minSizeLimit}.",
                                'emptyError'=>"{file} is empty, please select files again without it.",
                                'onLeave'=>"The files are being uploaded, if you leave now the upload will be cancelled."
                               ),
               'showMessage'=>"js:function(message){ alert(message); }"
               )

               ));
?>

    <?php //echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'fileName',array('maxlength'=>45)); ?>
    <?php //echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'user_id'); ?>

    <?php echo BsHtml::submitButton('Submit', array('color' => BsHtml::BUTTON_COLOR_PRIMARY)); ?>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Comment: Hi @Salik what's the problem? If I understand you can not save the video name in the database? while the video file is saved in the folder properly planned. so the lack of name in the database will not let you see the correct result in the view?

Comment: Exactly mate, the lack of name in the database will not let me see the video on the localhost/projectname/video/create

Comment: Are you sure the actionCreate are invoked when you press submit?

Comment: I think it is not because i made a upload function in the controller according to the steps given in the link of multiuploadfiles.. and that upload function is currently invoked to upload the video in the video directory.

Comment: First we try to understand where we stand, use the code that I have stated in the answer and tell me what you get

Comment: Nothing happens, it is working same as it was before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97314/discussion-between-salik-asad-and-scaisedge).

Comment: One hour, One hour and half .. i'm busy now..

Comment: oh ok, no problem, please share when you come up with something, thank you.

Comment: have you do what suggested..?

Comment: Yes i have tried, but it gives me the same result as it was giving me before.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't save the model in database, first check if data from submit are what you need and the model is saved without model validation.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Video;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
    if(isset($_POST){
      var_dump('ALL POST');
      var_dump($_POST);
    } else {
      var_dump('NO POST'); 
    }

    if(isset($_POST['video']))
    { 
        var_dump('VIDEO POST');
        var_dump($_POST['video']);

        $model->attributes=$_POST['video'];
        //$model->video = Video::getInstance($model, 'video');
        if($model->save(false))
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
    'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

If the var_dump show proper value and overriding the validation the value is saved in db the problem is in the validation rules.

and in the view try

```
<?php 

     echo "<br /> Video = : ".  $model->video  ."<br />";
?>
```

Comment: Explain me. What have showed the var_dump($_POST['video'])?

Comment: I tried the exact code which you have mentioned as the answer but it doesn't brings any change.. It is working as it was before.

Comment: @SalikAsad i not asked you if working or not but only what the var_dump instruction show in the browser. The var_dump show somethings or not.? Be clear please..

Comment: Hi @scaisEdge, i was working with videos today and did what you advised, the var_dump doesn't shows me anything, please help me doing this, thank you. I actually stopped working on videos as my teacher gave me some other task and asked me to work on videos later.

Comment: If the  `var_dump($_POST['Video']);` is not executed (doesn't show you nothings ) mean the $_POST[video'] is not set...then let's try checking if $_POST contain somethings..   i have update the answer for this. but are you sure the field with video is called 'Video'?

Comment: @caisEdge it shows me this "array (size=0) empty" and yes i have the field named "video", actually the table video has 3 objects "id(PK)"  "video" and "user_id(FK)"

Comment: Video and video are different .. are you sure is  lowercase..?

Comment: The name of the table is video(lowercase) and the name of the videofile is also video(lowercase).

Comment: I have update the answer and please try with the $_POST['video'] like in the answer.. give me  a feedback.. and keep attention i have inserted var_dump for show what's happen ..report me which var_dump are show

Comment: thanks for your such nice gesture, i have tried this as you said me. It gives me "string 'ALL POST' (length=8)", "array (size=0)empty". It is executing var_dump($_POST)

Comment: Do i have to use the upload function in the create function so that i can see the videos via URL "projectname/video/create"?

Comment: I don't undertstand you question.  After that var_dump($_POST) is show the program should go to create view ... and in this view you should create/upload you video.. and when submit you should show invar_dump($_POST) the value you just created ..

Comment: When i type the url "projectname/video/create" it prints the var_dump value on the top which is string 'ALL POST' (length=8) ,array (size=0) empty. And when I upload the video and submit the video it takes me to the view file. This is what I am getting mate.

Comment: And Then the next step which is? .. I.m not in your head.. what's you goal now?

Comment: actually in the view file it is showing me the id, user_id but not the name of the video file. The video column is empty.

Comment: In var_dump($_POST['video'])  you see the video value ..?

Comment: I have update the answer try adding the code provide for show the video value

Comment: It doesn't show me the video name/value.. I tried it in my view file. I tested it by $model->user_id, and it gives me the user id but not the video name.

Comment: If you don't see the video name in var_dump($_POST['video'])  and you don't see in model->video mean you haven't the video name- Your submit don't send the value... or you don't collect teh data in you create model..

Comment: Are you sure you see the video name in var_dump($_POST['video'])  and the code show 'VIDEO POST' path ..? ... please provide the Video model too

Comment: No it doesn't show "VIDEO POST", it shows "ALL POST" instead. and this is exactly what it shows. string 'ALL POST' (length=8), array (size=0) empty

Comment: If you see ALL POST after you submit the create model mean you don't have uploaded a name for video... is simple...

Comment: No i see ALL POST before the submit, not after submit, After submit i just see the view file with id, user_id, and video(empty column) on it.

Comment: If you don't see VIDEO POST mean   not passing by the saving of created model.. you send the model to another action?.. update the controller with you actual code and show me the create view please..

Comment: Yes you don't get the file uploaded      eg:        $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file'); i have update the answer

Comment: I also tried this one, it prints this on the top of the page after submit. string 'ALL POST' (length=8)

array (size=2)
  'video' => 
    array (size=1)
      'user_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'yt0' => string '' (length=0)

string 'VIDEO POST' (length=10)

array (size=1)
  'user_id' => string '1' (length=1)
And also gives me an fatal error: Call to undefined method Video::getInstance() in the video controller.

Comment: I dont know what the problem is though i followed every step of the multiuploadfile extension. I have updated the question with the current controller code and also the create view file. And thank you very much for your this amount of help. This is my last thing of the project, please help me in completing this.

Comment: I have commented the getIstance .. I have updated the code but I'm not in this kind of code you are providing .  This time i'm not able to help you..You havent the (video) file name in the model you created .. When you are in create view what do you do? show me also the _form you use in render partial of the create view.

Comment: When i am in the createview I just select the user from the dropdown(Select2 extension i have used for this) and I upload the video(which goes into the video folder upon submit) and i just submit it.  i have also updated the question with the _form file

Comment: i guess we should leave it, but thank you very very ,uch for your this great help.. Is there any other extension or any other way by which i can upload multiple videos on my view file.

Comment: I have looked at the code of the widget and at the extension http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eajaxupload/.. is clear that the widget don'get the file name and for this need some other part of code.. but i, looking at the doc  don't understand how this is possibile.  The file is upload but the filename is not provided.. i can't help. you..

Comment: Try using a simple one (not multiples) like this http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/how-to-upload-a-file-using-a-model/

Comment: Thank you mate, I will have a look at it, thank you again.